# Custom archive URL as a subfolder of the custom post type slug

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, custom-post-type-archives

I have a Custom Post Type called **Whatever**.

The slug for this CPT is **whatever**.

By default, I can access the posts archive in the frontend at */whatever* and each post at */whatever/post-slug*

But I would like to have a landing page for this section, which should be accessed at */whatever*.

This would collide with the archive, and hence, I want to move the archive to be accessed at */whatever/results*.

**Briefing up**:

I need to have a structure as follows:

*/whatever* (normal page with a slug set to whatever)
*/whatever/results* (archive for the whatever custom post type)
*/whatever/post-slug* (single post inside the whatever custom post type)

When registering the CPT, I can pass as an arg:

```
'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'whatever', 'with_front' => true],
```

But here, I need to have a subfolder, and doing:

```
'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'whatever/result', 'with_front' => true],
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: it doesn't have to collide, this looks like your solution to the collision problem, was there a reason you didn't ask about that instead? With the right changes a page at `whatever/` is possible, with multiple methods to do it with pros and cons

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for helping. But, how can I have a landing page accessible at `/whatever` and also an archive page at the same URL without them colliding?

Comment: ah I misunderstood

Comment: @TomJNowell All cool, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a different slug for the archive by setting `has_archive` to a string:

```
register_post_type(
    'whatever',
    array(
        'has_archive' => 'whatever/results',
        'rewrite'     => array(
            'slug' => 'whatever',
        ),
        // ...etc.
    )
);
```

I've tested that and it seems to do exactly what you needed.

Comment: Works like a charm. WP never ceases to amaze.